# Windows 7: Backup Libraries in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, backup, libraries

Is there a specific path or a registry where the library settings are stored. So that i can backup and restore my libraries when ever I restore my computer using an image or reinstall my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Library in Windows 7 is stored as an XML definition file that has a file extension of “.library-ms.” The file name is the actual library’s name. For example, the Documents Library is represented by an XML file called Documents.library-ms. Library descriptions are saved on disk in the

`%appdata% Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries` folder (also known as FOLDERID_Libraries).

source: http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/04/14/libraries-under-the-hood.aspx

With regard to backup/restore libraries, this option is included in the Backup/Restore. You can change the backup settings and in the **What do you want to backup? ** dialog select **Let me choose** and then you can check what libraries to backup.

Comment: I dont want to use windows backup so then can i just copy and paste the info to the library location whenever i reload the computer?

Comment: Yes, you can copy the library and the paste it after restoring your computer